# formatting string SyntaxError

Tags: python, string, format, multilinestring

I have this code in python:

```
"{0}.currentTime += 1;".format(hairSyst)
```

where `hairSyst` is a string defined earlier. I don't understand why I am getting a syntax error.  My aim is to set an expression inside maya, and the expression is a bit long, I paste the whole thing below, maybe you can suggest a better way to do it.

```
expr = ("if ({0}.autoOverlap == 1){".format(firstControl.getName())
        "{0}.currentTime += 1;".format(hairSyst)
        "{0}.currentTime += 1;".format(nucleus)
        "float $refresh_tx = {0}.translateX;".format(cube)
        "float $refresh_ty = {0}.translateY;".format(cube)
        "float $refresh_tz = {0}.translateZ;".format(cube)
        "float $refresh_rx = {0}.rotateX;".format(cube)
        "float $refresh_ry = {0}.rotateY;".format(cube)
        "float $refresh_rz = {0}.rotateZ;".format(cube)
        "}else if({0}.autoOverlap == 0){".format(firstControl.getName())
        "{0}.currentTime = 1;".format(hairSyst)
        "{0}.currentTime = 1;".format(nucleus)
        "}"
)
```

Comment: Is `expr` supposed to be a single string or a tuple of 13 strings?

Comment: you have to merge your format string and use `format` on it only once. and double the braces to escape them when needed

Comment: add a `+` after each line to concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

Better make it one `format`ing string:

```
expr = """if ({0}.autoOverlap == 1){{
          {1}.currentTime += 1;
          {2}.currentTime += 1;
          float $refresh_tx = {3}.translateX;
          float $refresh_ty = {3}.translateY;
          float $refresh_tz = {3}.translateZ;
          float $refresh_rx = {3}.rotateX;
          float $refresh_ry = {3}.rotateY;
          float $refresh_rz = {3}.rotateZ;
          }}else if({0}.autoOverlap == 0){{"
          {1}.currentTime = 1;
          {2}.currentTime = 1;
          }}""".format(firstControl.getName(), hairSyst, nucleus, cube)
```

Notice the use of `"""` triple quoting instead of `"` single quoting to format a multi-line string.

EDIT:

In case the original string contains `{ }`, we have to escape them by `{{ }}` as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> 6.1.3. Format String Syntax
>
> The str.format() method and the Formatter class share the same syntax
>   for format strings (although in the case of Formatter, subclasses can
>   define their own format string syntax).
>
> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
>   {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
>   text, which is copied unchanged to the output. **If you need to include
>   a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling:
>   {{ and }}.**

Comment: I already tried this, but I am getting:   hairSyst, nucleus)
# KeyError: '\n                  {1}'

Comment: @user3809642, I've doubled the `{` since we are using `{}` operator to format the string, we have to escape `{` by `{{`

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate those strings. Right now, `eval()` sees that you've passed in 13 strings, but `eval()` only takes a single string. So do something like this:

```
expr = ("if ({0}.autoOverlap == 1){ ".format(firstControl.getName()) + 
     "{0}.currentTime += 1; ".format(hairSyst) + 
     "{0}.currentTime += 1; ".format(nucleus) + 
     "float $refresh_tx = {0}.translateX; ".format(cube) + 
     "float $refresh_ty = {0}.translateY; ".format(cube) + 
     "float $refresh_tz = {0}.translateZ; ".format(cube) + 
     "float $refresh_rx = {0}.rotateX; ".format(cube) + 
     "float $refresh_ry = {0}.rotateY; ".format(cube) + 
     "float $refresh_rz = {0}.rotateZ; ".format(cube) + 
     "}else if({0}.autoOverlap == 0){ ".format(firstControl.getName()) + 
     "{0}.currentTime = 1; ".format(hairSyst) + 
     "{0}.currentTime = 1; ".format(nucleus) + 
     "}"
)
```

I additionally added spaces after each string to make sure they don't run into each other.

Comment: thanks, now I am getting this error though:

#     "{0}.currentTime = 1; ".format(nucleus) +
# ValueError: unmatched '{' in format #